# Android 4.1 How to read APN Details

Tags: android, mms

In `Android 4.1 (Jelly Beans)` cannot access the `APN` details. When i try to access the `APN` details using

```
final Cursor apnCursor = this.context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(Carriers.CONTENT_URI, "current"), null, null, null, null);
```

In my program I wanna send a mms without using the Intent.

This will return a error saying I don't have write apn permission to access the APN details.

Then I added the following line to android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS"/>
```

this prompt the error permission is only granted to system apps.

So how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send your MMS via the `Intent`.

For security reasons, you cannot read APN details without `WRITE_APN_SETTINGS`, and that permission requires your app to be signed by the same signing key that signed the firmware *or* for your app to be installed on the system partition (e.g., by a rooted device user).

Comment: cannot use the intent as it compress the images i'm gonna attached to it. i want to send the image without compressing.

Comment: @Buddhika: Then say that your app only works on rooted devices, and instruct users of your app to install your app on the system partition.

Comment: that can't be done. as my device is also no rooted. that's not the solution i expected. is there any other solution?

Comment: @Buddhika: Certainly there is no other solution for getting the APN details. Whether there is yet another means of sending an MMS, I cannot say.

Answer (score 0):

I think It is an compile bug. 
In my case (I want the same permission WRITE_APN_SETTINGS), after clean the project (Eclipse->project->clean). the compile error prompt will disappear.

Comment: this removes the compile time error.at run time still the error occurs

Comment: See following app, which use WRITE_APN_SETTINGS, https://github.com/mobileresearch/weibo_android_sdk. it is a normal application(non system application). The app use Chinese. I hope you can read simple Chinese.:)